# Royal TS, full screen mode

Tags: remote-desktop

Is there a proper full screen mode in [royal ts](https://www.royalapplications.com/ts/win/features)? In my case the RDP connection is looking blurred. If not, is there another tool that replaces Remote Desktop Connection? Remote Desktop Connection is always crashing atm, that is why I need a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the properties of the connection to use full screen mode when the connection view is not in embedded mode.

Go to properties of the connection -> Window Mode -> Open Connection in: External Window (Full Screen).

If the connection is open when you change the properties then you will need to close and re-open.  Then right click on the tab and select External Window.

Comment: Whew this worked for me - thank you.